# Is this essential functional programming feature missing from python?

Tags: python

I have a class in python that allows me to save a function (in a database) for later use. Now I need to have a method in the class that allows me to call this function on some arguments. Since I don't know how many arguments the function has ahead of time, I have to pass them in as list. This is where things fall apart because I can't find any way to get the argument to take its arguments from the tuple. In LISP this is very easy, since there's a keyword (well just one character) '@' for exactly this purpose:

```
(defmacro (call function arguments)
 `(,function ,@args))
```

Does python do this and I've just missed it somehow?
And if it doesn't, does anyone have a creative solution?

Comment: Actually this would be written as `(apply function arguments)` in Lisp (any dialect of Lisp, in fact). No macros necessary in this case.

Answer (score 12):

Python uses * for argument expansion. If you want keyword arguments, expand a dict using **. So the macro you showed would be:

```
def call(function, args):
    return function(*args)
```

But usually the Pythonic way is to just do the call inline. There actually is a function called apply() that does exactly this, but it is deprecated because the inline way is usually cleaner.

Comment: @Joe Doliner:  Thanks are nice.  The way this web site works, however, you have to click the "accept" check-mark under the answer you liked the best.  It's your question.  If this was helpful, mark it as accepted.  If you want more information, ask away.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not missing from python. [SaltyCrane](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) explains the use of *args and **kwargs much better than I could.